# Adding category attribute (select) via installer. Set defaut not working but get additional empty value

Tags: category-attribute, install-script

I'm trying to add a custom attribute to the category page. It will already show up but I only want to have the values Yes/No in it. Unfortunately there is always an empty, preselected value. So actually 3 values. I can't get rid of it! Can anyone point me in the right direction that only YES/No shows up? Preferably with "No" preselected. Thank you so much

```
<?php
    $installer = $this;
    $installer->startSetup();
    $attribute  = array(
    'label'             => 'Show in Parent Category',
    'type'              => 'int',
    'input'             => 'select',
    'default'            => 0,
    'sort_order'         => 2,
    'group'          => 'General Information',
    'backend'           => 'eav/entity_attribute_source_table',
    'global'            => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
    'visible'           => true,
    'required'          => false,
    'user_defined'      => true,
    'searchable'        => false,
    'filterable'        => false,
    'comparable'        => false,
    'visible_on_front'  => false,
    'visible_in_advanced_search' => false,
    'unique'            => false,
    'option'             => array (
                            'values' => 
                                array (
                                    '1' => 'Yes',
                                    '0' => 'No'
                                )
                            )
    );
    $installer->addAttribute('catalog_category', 'show_in_parent_category', $attribute);
    $installer->endSetup();
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove this in your definition:

```
'backend'           => 'eav/entity_attribute_source_table'
```

And add this

```
'source'           => 'eav/entity_attribute_source_boolean'
```

Also remove the `option` element.